# Wipe off after wudu

Tags: fiqh, sunnah, wudu, taharah

After making wudu, is it allowed to wipe the water off the face and other parts or must simply let the water to dry by itself?

What is the sunnah over that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hadhrat Aa'ishah (Radhiyallaahu Anhaa) narrates that Rasulullah (Sallallaahu Alayhi wa Sallam) had a cloth which he used after Wudhu (Tirmidhi V1 P89).

---

> Hadhrat Maymoonah (Radhiyallaahu Anhaa) says that once she presented a cloth to Rasulullah (Sallallaahu Alayhi wa Sallam) but he did not take it, instead he brushed the water off with his hands(Bukhaari V1 P267).

So both are proven in the Sunnah. It also depends on the individual's choice, temperament, health and season.

Allah Ta'aala knows best.

Answer (score -1):

The choice is yours...wipe dry or let it soak you...do what you please and neither is wrong

Islam is a din which has made life of a religious person easy，we complicate things